# rails test database errors with postgresql on OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

So I have recently migrated to postgresql, and have been having issues with my test database creation. Whenever I run a rake task it seems to destroy my ability to access the test database that I have created. For example, if I run the following command

```
createdb -Ouser -Eutf8 example_test
```

I can run tests perfectly, however if I run a rake task I will get the following error:

.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@standard/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:991:in `initialize': FATAL:  database "example_test" does not exist (PGError)

If I create a new test database like so:

```
createdb -Ouser -Eutf8 example2_test
```

Everything will work again, until I have to run a rake task. Does anyone know what this issue could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed the bug, by finding the following blog post about the topic: http://katrinaowen.com/2011/01/05/using-postgresql-with-rails-3-cucumber-and-rspec
In short, this was a bug with creating databases with rspec installed, view the link and run the commands to get it to work on your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have spent the past hour trying to fix this. This was such a silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can look at `log/development.log` to see why the database is being dropped? And look at the rake task code itself to see what it is doing.

Usually the test database is generated via `rake db:test:prepare` based on `config/database.yml`